# Partly loading comment and loading the remaining ones on mouse click via AJAX in MySQL and PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP code that displays 10 users' post. Now each post has 10 comment. What I want is to display two comments and whenver a user click on `More` button 5 more comments 
should be loaded via AJAX and appended to the 2 that is already displaying. When the `More` is clicked again, it should load the remaing three and append them.

```
// for each post, load 2 comment
  $qry = "SELECT user_id, comment FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 2";
  $q = $conn->prepare($qry) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $conn->errorInfo()));
  $q->bindParam(1, $post_id);
  $q->execute();
  if($commentz = $q->fetchAll()){
  echo "<div class = 'comment_data'>";
     foreach ($commentz as $comment){
       echo "<div class = 'per_comment'>";
       echo "<p>". $comment[0] ." ". $comment[1] . "</p>";
       echo "</div>";
     }
  echo "<button class='mmore pacedown' name = 'more' type='submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'></span>More</button>";
  echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Plan is as follows:
create a javascript ajax function that passes last comment identifier and returns five next elements from server, appends these five to existing list, hides the current "more" button and adds new one at the end.
Resource:
[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)